# SQL Can a crosstab two different sets of value into the same table?

Tags: sql, ms-access, ms-access-2003

I am still on the same problem than there : [How to write a SQL function into Acces 2003](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45371090/how-to-write-a-sql-function-into-acces-2003).

I learned how to use a crosstab query into acces 2003 ( both through writing SQL directly and using the assistance wizard)  .

So right now, thanks to the crosstab query I got :

```
|Client ID||Product ID||Total Sell Dones||Total Sell Planed||Total Forecast Sell|
```

Thing is, I would like to add the quantity following a same scheme

```
|Client ID||Product ID||Total Sell Dones||Total Sell Planed||Total Forecast Sell||Quantity Sell Dones||Quantity Sell Planed||Quantity Forecast|
```

My cross tab query starts with  :

```
TRANSFORM Last(Data.Sells) AS CountOfSells SELECT....
```

I tried doing :

```
TRANSFORM Last(Data.Sells) AS CountOfSells  , Last(Data.quantity) as CountOfQuantity SELECT....
```

But it doesn't work. It looks like transform can only "transform" a single row and it can't transform two different rows?

I really need this crosstab thing query sorted out and I am already very thankful for the help.

Comment: look here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21142765/crosstab-with-2-or-more-row-names

Comment: Also http://allenbrowne.com/ser-67.html#MultipleValues